# In image classification how to count correct label?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

I have a basic classification problem; 2 classes to classify 0 or 1. I have trained my model using `Keras VGG16` but how to count the number of correct label? or the number of all images under label 0?
Assuming my model should distinguish between cats and dogs, how to count how many correctly labeled cats are there in validation set predicted by the model? I do have the accuracy but I need to access the count number.

This is my model:

```
#base_mode= VGG16()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
#model.add(base_model)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,4,3, input_shape= (32,32,3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="binary_crossentropy" , metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 50
history = model.fit(x=train_ds, y=train_lb , epochs=epochs, validation_data= (test_ds, test_lb) )
```

`train_lb` and `test_lb` have corresponding labels for the training/testing dataset, it's an array containing either 0 or 1. For example, the label for `train_ds[0]` would be `train_lb[0]`

Comment: No way to answer this without knowing details about your `train_lb` and `test_lb`; the model structure you have posted here is largely irrelevant to what you are asking.

Comment: `train_lb` and `test_lb` have corresponding labels for the training/testing dataset, it's an array containing either 0 or 1. For example, the label for `train_ds[0]` would be `train_lb[0]`

Comment: I get that, and this is not what my comment was about; what I said is - if you have an issue with how exactly to get the labels from the data, focus your post on the *data*, not on the (irrelevant) model architecture.

Comment: I don't have any issues with my labels and the model is working fine with 93% accuracy. My question is about AFTER training this model itself and about the accuracy report. I want to count the actual output of the model. I do already know the input but I don't know what was lost.. In my test dataset I had 100 data of label 0, how to know how many label 0 did my model predict?

Comment: As I implied, your *exact* question is quite unclear. Where is the model prediction code in your post? Do you have issues seeing the prediction labels, or getting the predictions themselves in the first place? And in both cases, showing the model structure is irrelevant (for the third time...).

Comment: I have issues getting the predictions themselves and I don't understand them. I have used this function `model.predict(test_ds)` and I got the array but this isn't what I need (since I need a counter of every correctly labeled data point). Since I'm very new to this I really don't know if I need to specify the metrics in `model.compile`, so I think it's relevant.

Comment: Since you have issues with the predictions themselves and you don't understand them, why don't you *post these predictions* here (possibly along with `model.compile()`), and explain **exactly** why `model.predict()` does not do what you want to do? Why posting the irrelevant (for the 4th time...) model structure and `model.fit()` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have all this info at once, I think the easier way would be to do a confusion matrix, that will show you how everythin is classified:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.title("Confusion matrix")
cf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
group_names = ["True Neg", "False Pos", "False Neg", "True Pos"]
group_counts = ["{0:0.0f}".format(value) for value in
                cf_matrix.flatten()]
group_percentages = ["{0:.2%}".format(value) for value in
                     cf_matrix.flatten()/np.sum(cf_matrix)]
labels = [f"{v1}\n{v2}\n{v3}" for v1, v2, v3 in zip(group_names,group_counts,group_percentages)]
labels = np.asarray(labels).reshape(2,2)
print(sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=labels, fmt="", cmap='Blues'))
```

Comment: What is the difference between y_test and y_pred? How to access y_pred?

Comment: y_pred is the prediction you make after training your model. y_test is the part of the y you should have left "untouched" to test your model at the end. You create your y_test using some tool like train_test_split for example :  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html